# reading directory in linux using c program

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I am trying to create a simple file server in c in linux. The idea is that, i enter the name of the file to be transfered from  the server on the client side. The server recives that file name as once the connection is established..But  whatever argument i pass it always open first file in the current directory. This is the server code

```
getcwd(buf3, sizeof(buf3));
dirp = opendir(buf3);

while (dptr = readdir(dirp)) {
    if (strcmp(buf, dptr->d_name) == 0);
        break;
    printf("%s\n", dptr->d_name);
}

string(dptr->d_name);
f = fopen(namelist[n1]->d_name, "r");

//f1=fopen(buf,"r");
if (f1 == NULL)
    err_sys("open error");

while (1)           //service client till it closes connection
{
    fgets(buf2, 50, f1);

    buflen = strlen(buf2);
    printf("Data Read From File: %d\n", buflen);

    if ((n = send(clifd, buf2, buflen, 0)) < 0)
        err_sys("send error");
    else if (n == 0) {
        printf("\nNo Data Recieved");
        break;
    }

    buf2[n] = 0;
};              //end of inner while

close(clifd);
fclose(f1);
exit(0);
```

Comment: So your problem is that the fopen(namelist...) doesn't open a file from the directory you expect?  Have you tried printf-ing the value of namelist[n1]->d_name to debug it?

Answer (score 7):

```
if(strcmp(buf,dptr->d_name)==0);
    break;
```

Should be:

```
if(strcmp(buf,dptr->d_name)==0) {
    break;
}
```

It's escaping your while loop immediately.

Comment: it does open file. But not the one i expect. It always open first file in current working directory.. Like i have "danish.txt" in my current working directory and want to transfer that to client..But it a always open the first one and transfer that to client.

Comment: Even after doing the changes that you have suggested... now i get error.../fileserverfinal1.exe 1200
Client Requested danish.txt
 File For Transfer
The file identifier is: -1
open error: Bad address

Comment: I'm almost sure that the error of adding a semi-colon after then condition would have been caught by `-Wall -Wextra` flags to `gcc`